# Передача данных по Bluetooth Arduino-Android - проблема с приемом

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

На основе сэмпла BluetoothChat из Android Studio сделал приложение, с ардуинки принимаю данные, проблема моя ровно такая же, как в этом [посте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231598/how-to-read-all-bytes-together-via-bluetooth). Там и ответ есть, который должен сработать, но я новенький в программировании и мне не совсем понятно, куда и как добавить кусочек кода из ответа. Суть ясна и понятна, что программа будет ждать, пока не придет все сообщение до знака #, а потом его отправит на дальнейшую обработку. Прошу помочь разобраться, как исправить эту проблему, как добавить тот код? Либо может есть еще какие-то решения

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем то, что хотелось бы получить в ответ, но проблему решил подключением этой [библиотеки](https://github.com/OmarAflak/Bluetooth-Library). Правда половину проекта переделать под нее придется, но тем не менее эта библиотека работает на порядок лучше стокового сэмпла с блютуз чатом